# Textures only work in compat and glGetError Always INVALID_ENUM as soon as context is open

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am having some issues with textures when using OpenGL 3.3 Core.

If I use the compat profile it renders perfectly. I tried to debug by using the glGetError()

It returns an invalid enum after getting a vao. And returns the same during the main loop. But surely thats not the issue? - It woudld be impossible to have an error by that point.

I was under the impressning that calling glGetError() would clear the error so the next call would just show the errors between the two?

My Platform is Windows7 64 with a nVidia GTX580 with driver version 310.70.

For my loading lib I am using glload at the min however I have used GLEW also. 
I am using the GLFW to manage the OpenGL context and DevIL to load texures. I am building in VS2010.

Here is a link to my full source. (I have riped everything from my main program out and named variable as logicly as possible)

[full source code](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15586644/so.cpp)

Code that mostly likely to cause the problem.

Loading the image with devIL and buffering to the GPU.

```
void loadImage(const char* imageFile)
{
    ILuint texid; 
    ilGenImages(1, &texid); 
    ilBindImage(texid); 

    ilLoadImage(imageFile);

    int size = ilGetInteger( IL_IMAGE_SIZE_OF_DATA ) ;
    ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE); 


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1,&textureBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBuffer);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
         0, 
         ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP), 
         ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),
         ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT), 
         0, 
         ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_FORMAT),
         GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
         ilGetData());

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    ilDeleteImages(1, &texid);


}
```

Render function called from the main loop.

```
void render()
{
    glUseProgram(program);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementObject);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureBuffer);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(8*4));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0); 

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Vertex shader

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 coords;
smooth out vec2 textureCO;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x,position.y,0.0,1.0);
    textureCO = coords;

}
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;
smooth in vec2 textureCO;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
void main()
{
    vec4 textureColor = texture(texture1, textureCO);
    outputColor = textureColor;
}
```

Comment: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is not valid in a core profile context. It *should* in fact, set the error flag.

Comment: Ok, with them ripped out the texture renderers all black.

Comment: source now has glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and disabled remove. Problem still exsists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the question of getting a `GL_INVALID_ENUM`, this is a common problem with the GLEW library.  It's documented [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) on opengl.org.  Just clear the error (by calling `glGetError`, like you say) and then OpenGL error reporting will behave as normal (or more precisely, as you're expecting).

As for the texture problem, it may be related to the call to `ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP)`.  In core profiles, the internal format may only be one of the specified image formats, while according to the DevIL documentation, `ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP)` returns an integer value of the number of bytes per pixel.  `glTexImage*D` under compatibilty mode will accept values of 1, 2, 3, or 4 for the internal format, but those values will also generate a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error under a core profile.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will be on my main machine this afternoon and I will get back to you. +1

Comment: still having issues. currently glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
   0, 
   GL_RGBA, 
   ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),
         ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT), 
   0, 
   GL_RGBA,
   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
         ilGetData()); What are texels? the opengl docs say width and hight should be 1024 + from how im reading it.

Comment: Working now. still getting the enum error but core works! thanks

Comment: @Andrew Happy to help.  To answer your question about "texels", it's short for "Texture Elements" in the same way "pixel" is for "Picture Element".